# How to parse DateTimeOffset with 'z' pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, parsing, datetimeoffset

I need to convert `string` to `DateTimeOffset`.
I need to support the following formats:

```
+-05:00
+-05
+-5 // can't process with this one 'z' does not work here
```

I have the following code sample:

```
DateTimeOffset Parse(string input, string pattern)
{
    return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(input, pattern,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None);
}

try
{
    var testData = new (string input, string pattern)[3]
    {
        ("+01:10", "zzz"),
        ("-01", "zz"),
        ("+1", "z") // DOES NOT WORK
    };

    foreach (var test in testData)
    {
        var result = Parse(test.input, test.pattern);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Offset.TotalMinutes);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{//in case of "+1", "z" I get Input string was not in a correct format.
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: use "%z".    See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#UsingSingleSpecifiers

Comment: @Ralf thanks it works